# Adding a custom feature to SXA scaffolding

Tags: sxa

If I want my custom feature to be install-able whenever a new tenant or site is created, what are the steps?

Is creating an item of type `/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Scaffolding/Roots/SiteSetupRoot` or  `/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Scaffolding/Roots/TenantSetupRoot` under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/Experience Accelerator` enough?  Do these custom SetupRoot's need to be registered anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

No, all you need to do is to create `SiteSetupRoot`/`TenantSetupRoot` somewhere under:

- `/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature`
- `/sitecore/system/Settings/Foundation`

Script is smart enough to find everything located there and your feature will be then displayed in a dialog:

**Feature Definition**
[image]

**New Site - features list**
[image]